# how can i put data in to a queue and read it at the same time?

Tags: python, multithreading, serial-port, queue, multiprocessing

i'm trying to put in a multi procesing queue some data from serial port, and reading this data fom the queue with another thread, but it seems that the queue can't be acces for read until writing task is done :/

```
import Queue  #

cola = Queue.Queue()
s_port = '/dev/ttyUSB' + sys.argv[1]
b_rate = 9600

ser = serial.Serial(
    port=s_port,
    baudrate=b_rate,
    timeout=1
)


class worker: 
    def __init__(self,cola,ser): 
        self.cola = cola 
        self.ser = ser 

    def read_serial(self,ser): 
        ser.flushInput()
        while True : 
            inp = ser.read(size=1) 
            byte = inp.encode('hex')
            print cola.qsize()  #just for debug 
            self.cola.put(byte)

    def go(self): 
        th1 = threading.Thread(target=self.read_serial, args=[ser]) 
        th1.start() 

class worker2: 
    def __init__(self,cola,): 
        self.cola = cola 
        self.ser = ser 

    def getrx(self,cola): 
        while True : 
            rx = self.cola.get()
            print str(rx)
        pass 

    def go2(self): 
        th2 = threading.Thread(target=self.getrx, args=[cola])
        th2.start() 

t = worker(cola,ser)
t.go()
t2 = worker2(cola) 
t2.go2()
```

any ideas?

Comment: First, why are you using `multiprocessing.Queue` instead of `queue.Queue` for threads? That shouldn't cause a problem, but it does make your code more confusing, and slower on most platforms too.

Comment: Second, you should _never_ write a loop like `while cola.qsize() > 0:`. As the documentation explicitly says, "Note, qsize() > 0 doesn’t guarantee that a subsequent get() will not block". The right thing to do is just call `get`, and handle the `Empty` exception.

Comment: i try first with queue.queue, but with the same result, so i read that queue.queue is designed to work with one process, that's why, but anyway the result is exactly the same :/

Comment: and sorry youre right about the while, is just one of my multiple attempts to get it working, but any way it never let  objet getrx work, i comment the entire loop, an just put print "x" and it never prints

Comment: You only have one process, with two threads, which is exactly what `queue.Queue` is designed to work with. You're not creating a `multiprocessing.Process` or `Pool` anywhere, are you? Just changing random things without understanding them never makes your code better.

Comment: Meanwhile, if commenting the entire loop and just printing `x` causes the same problem… why did you ask the question this way? If the code has the same problem even when nobody touches the queue, how could the queue possibly be relevant?

Comment: as i say, just one of multiple attempts, and many tnks for ur advices,

Comment: yeap, tnks for notice that, but coul you answer the question? u can ignore my code, just how can write a queue an reading it at the same time, if u have time and patience of course XD

Comment: If you actually had two threads running simultaneously, there is literally nothing you have to do to write and read to a queue at the same time. Just call `q.put` in one thread and `q.get` in the other (without checking `qlen`) and it always works. The only reason your code doesn't work is that you never start the threads at all, you just run the worker1 code in the main thread forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here has nothing to do with queues.

This line:

```
th1 = threading.Thread(target=self.read_serial(ser))
```

… calls `self.read_serial(ser)`, and passes the result as the `target` to run on the background thread. And this function runs forever, so nothing else ever gets to happen.

What you want to do is to *pass* the method, not *call* it.

```
th1 = threading.Thread(target=self.read_serial, args=[ser])
```

You have the same problem in `worker2`, and need to fix that as well.

---

So, once you fix that, and the other problems, what else do you have to do to let one thread put to the queue and the other get from the queue at the same time?

Nothing. It just works, automatically. Just call `put` in one thread, and `get` in the other. If there's nothing to get yet in the reader thread, the `get` will just block and not return until the other thread does a `put`, and then it will immediately wake up.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/HdtHPUa8) is an example that's as similar as possible to your starting code. There's an even simpler example in the [`Queue`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) documentation.

Comment: it doesnt work, just for debug i print a cola.qsize(), just before cola.get(), befor i made the changes it prints an incremental numbre, after it prints always 0 :/

Comment: What is the "it doesn't work"? If you need help with something, you have to show the code you're running, not make me guess at it.

Comment: Look [here](http://pastebin.com/HdtHPUa8). This is basically your code, with this bug fixed, and some functions stubbed out. When I run this, it prints out `61` once/second forever. Of course the queue length is always 0 after that, because as soon as something gets posted to the queue by the other thread, I grab it and use it, but that's not a problem.

Comment: @Dat30: I've already explained that nobody can help you if you just say things like "gives me an error". Am I supposed to guess everything you might possibly have done and tell you how to solve every single possibility?

Comment: when i have "target=self.read_serial(ser)" it always read from serial and put the byte in to queue,i know it because it prints incremental number in qsize, with your fix it doesnt print the get, it just print the size in 0

Comment: sorry man, english isn not my native language, :/ i'm trying to explain myself, as well as i can :(

Comment: @Dat30: I already explained that. `target=self.read_serial(ser)` calls `read_serial` immediately, on the main thread, waits for it to return, and passes the result as the `target`. Because `read_serial` never returns, it just runs forever on the main thread; no other threads even get created.

Comment: i know that you alreadi explain it, i just say wath happend when i make the changes that you suggested, serial never reads

Comment: sorry man, it works, just fine,  ser.flushInput() was the problem, i forgot it was there  XD

Comment: @Dat30: My example doesn't read from the serial, it just fakes it by returning 'a' over and over. The whole point of an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) is to eliminate all the extraneous stuff and come up with a simple example that demonstrates the problem, which you can get a simple solution for.